# Create a textbox and select the last one

Tags: c#

I have this code to create a text box.

How can I select automatically the last textbox I've created?

```
        TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
        panel1.Controls.Add(t1);
        t1.Top = leftcontrol * 17;
        t1.Left = 100;
        t1.Text = "TextBox" + this.leftcontrol.ToString();
        leftcontrol = leftcontrol + 1;
```

thanks

Comment: Which framework are you using? Winforms? Webforms? MVC?

Comment: what do you mean by "select"? move the focus, i.e. move the cursor to that box so the user can type, or do you mean how to programatically get a hold of the TextBox Object that was created last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the TextBox.Focus() function on the last created text box.

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
panel1.Controls.Add(t1);
t1.Top = leftcontrol * 17;
t1.Left = 100;
t1.Text = "TextBox" + this.leftcontrol.ToString();
t1.Focus();
leftcontrol = leftcontrol + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms, and there are only the TextBoxes you added to the Panel:

```
panel1.Controls[panel1.Controls.Count - 1].Focus();
```

If you are still in that same block of code, then just use:

```
t1.Focus();
```